# Scenario Analysis/Long Format Database Manipulation - Differencing within a data frame based on multiple criteria

Tags: r, plyr

I am processing a large amount of data output from a scenario analysis. One of the most common type of figure that I generate in this analysis is a difference plot (be it a stacked area or stacked column) that shows the changes in a value between a base case scenario and another scenario over a period of years. In order to create this type of plot, I of course need the values differenced by year. For example, the below (fake) data shows electricity generation from coal, gas, and nuclear generating technologies in the years 2010, 2020, and 2030.

```
t.data = data.frame(cbind(c(rep('base',9),rep('scen1',9),rep('scen2',9)),
                      c(rep(c(2010,2020,2030),9)),
                      c(rep('coal',3),rep('gas',3),rep('nuclear',3))),
                      c(1000,950,850,500,600,700,400,300,300,1000,800,
                        600,500,650,850,400,400,400,1000,700,400,500,700,800,400,200,100))

colnames(t.data) = c('scen','year','tech','gen')
```

These commands should result in the following data:

```
    scen year    tech  gen
1   base 2010    coal 1000
2   base 2020    coal  950
3   base 2030    coal  850
4   base 2010     gas  500
5   base 2020     gas  600
6   base 2030     gas  700
7   base 2010 nuclear  400
8   base 2020 nuclear  300
9   base 2030 nuclear  300
10 scen1 2010    coal 1000
11 scen1 2020    coal  800
12 scen1 2030    coal  600
13 scen1 2010     gas  500
14 scen1 2020     gas  650
15 scen1 2030     gas  850
16 scen1 2010 nuclear  400
17 scen1 2020 nuclear  400
18 scen1 2030 nuclear  400
19 scen2 2010    coal 1000
20 scen2 2020    coal  700
21 scen2 2030    coal  400
22 scen2 2010     gas  500
23 scen2 2020     gas  700
24 scen2 2030     gas  800
25 scen2 2010 nuclear  400
26 scen2 2020 nuclear  200
27 scen2 2030 nuclear  100
```

What I'd like to do is create a new column (e.g. gen.diff.base) that shows the difference in generation by technology and year between the exploratory scenarios (scen1 & scen2) and the base case scenario (base). Such that the following would be created:

```
    scen year    tech  gen gen.diff.base
1   base 2010    coal 1000             0
2   base 2020    coal  950             0
3   base 2030    coal  850             0
4   base 2010     gas  500             0
5   base 2020     gas  600             0
6   base 2030     gas  700             0
7   base 2010 nuclear  400             0
8   base 2020 nuclear  300             0
9   base 2030 nuclear  300             0
10 scen1 2010    coal 1000             0
11 scen1 2020    coal  800          -150
12 scen1 2030    coal  600          -250
13 scen1 2010     gas  500             0
14 scen1 2020     gas  650            50
15 scen1 2030     gas  850           150
16 scen1 2010 nuclear  400             0
17 scen1 2020 nuclear  400           100
18 scen1 2030 nuclear  400           100
19 scen2 2010    coal 1000             0
20 scen2 2020    coal  700          -250
21 scen2 2030    coal  400          -450
22 scen2 2010     gas  500             0
23 scen2 2020     gas  700           100
24 scen2 2030     gas  800           100
25 scen2 2010 nuclear  400             0
26 scen2 2020 nuclear  200          -100
27 scen2 2030 nuclear  100          -200
```

Note that the difference shown is always scen# minus base (for the corresponding year and technology). My gut says that there is a simple way to calculate this new column with ddply or tapply, but I can't quite work it out. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks R world!

As an aside, if someone can show me how to do this with ddply that would be worth extra bonus thanks!

Best,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. For those interested, here's the code:

```
ddply(t.data, .(scen,year,tech), mutate, 
           gen.diff.base = gen - t.data$gen[which(t.data$scen=='base' & t.data$year==year
                                              & t.data$tech==tech)])
```